# Linux grep only n,m character strings

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a file which has below contents,

```
TESTING
TSET24D
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
MSDWEHLKGY
```

and want to grep the strings only 6 and 8 characters long.

I tried the below one,

```
[root@server ~]# cat listfile | grep -o -w -E '^[[:alnum:]]{6,8}'
TESTING
TSET24D
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
[root@server ~]#
```

which seems to work on some servers and its returing the strings between 6-8 also coming.

Any idea please..

Comment: You don't need to `cat` the file, `grep` will read the file for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex, `{6,8}` looks for a repetition between 6 and 8 times (so 7 is included).  You need to use a pipe (OR in regex) to split the search for only 6 OR 8 times.

```
$ grep -o -w -E '^[[:alnum:]]{6}|^[[:alnum:]]{8}' listfile
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
```

Comment: Just add `$`s to anchor it.

Comment: @EdMorton correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the `-w` option do this?

Comment: Good point, then you don't need the `^` anchor either. So you either need (`^` and `$`) or (`-w` or `-x`). You also don't need `-o`. Actually, I'm not sure what the OP means by `I need to filter only alpha numeric characters along with it.` in his comment since there are no non-alpha-numeric characters in his sample input so I'm not really sure WHAT you do need, but whatever it is, it's not what you have...

Comment: @EdMorton `^` represents the start of a line rather than the start of a word and `-w` means `grep` will match only whole words. I took the assumption that he was wanting to match the first whole word at the start of a line based on what the questioner already had and along with the `-o` option, this is exactly what is returned.  Unless you can see something that I don't and assuming my assumptions were correct, I think my answer pretty much has it covered.

Comment: I understand all of that but if the OPs input data is as shown, one word per line, then you don't need to match whole words AND the start of a line because each line is a whole word. You also don't need `-o` for the same reason. Your answer will produce the expected output, it's just doing some things that aren't necessary but since the OP hasn't shown us input containing non-alphanumeric characters we don't know what subset of the constructs you're using are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Awk` with its `POSIX` compliant `length()` function,

```
awk '(length($0)==6 || length($0)==8) && $0 ~ /[[:alnum:]]{6}|[[:alnum:]]{8}/' file
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
```

works fine for a input file as

```
TESTING
TSET24D
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
MSDWEHLKGY
------
--------
------a
@1234$21
```

(or)

more simply as Ed Morton suggests, just do

```
awk '/^([[:alnum:]]{6}|[[:alnum:]]{8})$/' file
```

Comment: Try this -  `awk '/[[:alnum:]]/ && (length($0)==6 || length($0)==8)' ff`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR That would return anything of length 6 or 8 with one single [[:alnum:]] in it, for example `-------a`.

Comment: @Inian Looks like one single quote is missing with that

Comment: @Inian its not working for me, `[root@server ~]# awk '(length($0)==6 || length($0)==8) && $0 ~ /[[:alnum:]]{6}|[[:alnum:]]{8}/' listfile
[root@server ~]#`

Comment: @Karthi1234: Post the contents of the file, for which it is not working

Comment: @Inian, here it is `[root@server ~]# cat listfile
TESTING
TSET24D
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
MSDWEHLKGY
[root@server ~]#
`

Comment: and what is your expected output of this and what is your `awk` version? it works fine for me giving, `DSWEDFBG WTSETO`

Comment: @Inian Exepcted output is same what you said. Awk version is 3.1.5.

Comment: @Karthi1234: It is working fine for me, do you have contents of file copied from a Windows machine? Remove the `CRLF` endings by `dos2unix listfile` before running `awk`

Comment: You don't need `(length($0)==6 || length($0)==8) && $0 ~`, just stick `^` and `$` around what's left - `awk '/^([[:alnum:]]{6}|[[:alnum:]]{8})$/' file`.

Comment: @Karthi1234: It was working fine for me, why did you _unaccept_ the answer? Can you try `awk '/^([[:alnum:]]{6}|[[:alnum:]]{8})$/' file` too?

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
awk '/^......(..)?$/' file
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
```

The same for `[[:alnum:]]`s:

```
$ awk '/^[[:alnum:]]{6}([[:alnum:]]{2})?$/' file
DSWEDFBG
WTSETO
```

Comment: Your first solution does not match whole words, merely any string 6 or 8 chars long.  Symbols, spaces or anything else would be included.

Comment: @KindStranger You are right but the OP says: _strings only 6 and 8 characters long_ and the requirement to _filter only alpha numeric characters_ came later as a comment in an answer. Therefore two answers to satisfy two requirements. Oh you actually downvoted on that? Oh wow.